# how to modify android.os.Build's static field?

Tags: java, android

I want to modify android.os.Build static field like DEVICE,MODEL,HARDWARE and etc . what i check in internet , it's possible with exposed framework but i can't do this well and I'm a bit confused ! Does anyone have an experience about this problem ? 
Thank in advanced

Answer (score 2):

The Android Operating System doesn't allow anyone to modify or change these fields.
You can not do this even if you have a rooted Android.
There are many tutorials online, which are useless.